# How to extract a first html tags in each group with the help of xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

How can I extract the first element in each group with the help of XPath? I mean to get a list of elements with class "first" from such situation, for example:

```
<div class="parent">
        <table class="first">  ... </table>
        <table> ... </table>
        <table> ... </table>
        <p> ... </p>
        <div> ... </div>
        <table class="first"> ... </table>
        <table> ... </table>
        <p> ... </p>
        <p> ... </p>
        <table class="first"> ... </table>
    </div>
```

Note: Class "first" is only for illustration. In my code, there are no classes as such, so I cannot choose with the help of CSS or XPath class search.

Comment: I guess there is no way to get the `table` tag with a single xpath, as there is no actual pattern within your html/xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate all the children of the parent `<div>` and iterate over them. If the tag name is `<table>` after any other tag add it to the list.

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".parent > "));
List<WebElement> firstElements = new ArrayList<>(WebElement);

boolean lookForFirst = true;
for (WebElement item : items) {
    if (item.getTagName().equals("table")) {
        if (lookForFirst) {
            firstElements.add(item);
            lookForFirst = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        lookForFirst = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `(/div[@class=parent]/table)[1]` and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@class=parent]//table[@class='first']
```